# How can I use Kivy and Python to make my dot "ping?"

Tags: python, kivy

I am making a way finding software for a large building. The link below is to an image of my code, which is using Kivy. How do I erase the dot, and make it reappear again at timed intervals for a "ping" effect?

Thanks

Link: https://gyazo.com/41a062ab37c4a0643b74b47d0bf689ef

Comment: Consider using `Clock.schedule_interval()`.

Comment: I see this could work...but how would the code work? I can't seem to get it through my thick skull.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a call to `Clock.schedule_interval()` to call a method that implements the blinking effect that you want:

```
def btn_centrum(self):
    with self.canvas:
        Color(1,0,0,.5, mode='rgba')
        self.rect = Rectangle(pos=(277,650), size=(10,10))
        self.opacity = 2
    Clock.schedule_interval(self.blink, 0.5)

def blink(self, dt):
    if self.opacity == 2:
        self.opacity = 0
    else:
        self.opacity = 2
```

A few additional comments:

- While creating a class named `FloatLayout` will work, it is bad practice to create a `Widget` with the same name as an existing kivy `Widget`.
- When you post a question here, please post the code and not an image of the code. It's easier for both of us if you just copy/paste your code into your question.

Comment: When I added that code in...it just made my entire screen UI blink in and out. Any idea on how to isolate it to just the Elllipse?

Comment: Whatever `self` is will blink. If you want just the Rectangle to blink, then that `blink` method should be a method of, for example, the `FloatLayout` class that is in your posted image.